# Chisq.test and Goodness-of-fit

Tags: r, chi-squared

I just read this article, http://ccnmtl.columbia.edu/projects/qmss/the_chisquare_test/about_the_chisquare_test.html, specifically the section on the goodness-of-fit test. I even computed the chi-square value the old fashioned way, and got it right (13.6)!

I have a few questions:

1. From the article: "We then compare the value calculated in the formula above to a standard set of tables. The value returned from the table is 1.8%.". This is the value returned by the chisq.test in the p-value. How does the function calculate the p-value?
2. The p-value indicates that there is a 1.8% probability that the die is fair. Is this the same as saying that I am (100 - 1.8) 98.2% confident that the die is unfair?
3. Is there a way of calling the chisq.test() function passing a confidence factor of 99%?
4. Finally, should I be using the chisq.test() function on the actual observations, or on a contingency table derived from the observations?

Thank you for your help/pointers/advice.

Richard Rogers

Comment: most of these are stat questions, you'd get better answers from the stat nerds at [cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) 1) `pchisq(13.6, 5, lower.tail = FALSE)`, 2) neither of those are correct. the article interprets it correctly: "the chance of getting a statistic as large or larger than the one calculated above is only 1.8%" 3) there's no need for that, the statistic is calculated based on the collected data, 4) you can do both, there are examples in `?chisq.test`

Comment: Agree with @rawr, this should be migrated to http://stats.stackexchange.com/ . The answers are fairly straightforward, but the question should be migrated